# How to hide the profile2 header for profile?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I have the module profile2 for user profiles with different fields on my site. At the moment I am theming the user profile page.

I want to hide the header for profile-specific fields and show them with the common fields. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What header are we talking about?

Comment: @Clive http://imgur.com/GctO1Pq

Comment: Please edit the question and describe what you mean (adding the image will probably be useful too)